# Using jOOQ, how to get data type of a column by name

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to get the data type of a field by name.  I found the method `getDataType` which works great if I know the field (e.g. MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN_NAME.getDataType()).

But I want to find it by field name (e.g. `aDSL.fieldByName("my_column_name").getDataType()`) where aDSL is of type `DSLContext`.

I want this because I am building a generic sort function on a collection used from the result set and I'd prefer to not rely on a developer to pass in the right data type for my comparator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"But I want to find it by field name"* - what does that mean? Where do you want to *"find it from"*? And why do you need the data type? It would help to better understand your use-case, in order to answer this question

Comment: @LukasEder - I didn't want to refer to the the field by it's "formal" name, e.g. MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN, I wanted to refer to it as the name it's known as in the Result.   I put more information in the solution I found.   Thanks for all your responses -- it's great to see someone take such pride and ownership in their product and I appreciate your time and your answers (not just to my questions, but all the others that you've answered - you're saving me a ton of time!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types are available from `Result` or `Record` via:

```
Class<?> type1 = result.field("MY_COLUMN").getType()
Class<?> type2 = record.field("MY_COLUMN").getType()
```

See:

- [`Result.field(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#field-java.lang.String-)
- [`Record.field(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#field-java.lang.String-)
- [`Field.getType()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#getType--)

But most standard data types are `Comparable` anyway ([I'm looking at the use-case in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33742181/521799)), so why not just use Java 8's new [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) and perhaps [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--)

Answer (score 1):

I was building a custom `Comparator` (I took my result set and converted it to a List, storing the Record - among other things - so that I could do all manner of manipulation on it, sorting, filtering, etc).   In order to build the Comparator, I needed the type:

```
switch (R1.dataRecord.getValue( element ).getClass().toString())
{
   case "class java.lang.Long":
      compareResult = ( (Long) R1.dataRecord.getValue( element ) ).compareTo( (Long) R2.dataRecord.getValue( element ) );
      if (compareResult != 0)
           return compareResult * compareOrder;
           break;
   case "class java.lang.String":
      compareResult = ( (String) R1.dataRecord.getValue( element ) ).compareTo( (String) R2.dataRecord.getValue( element ) );
      if (compareResult != 0)
           return compareResult * compareOrder;
      break;
    ... etc ...
}
```

I was able to get the type from the record.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's creative :) I've added another answer, just in case this helps...